# Spring Framework 4.0 Sample application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-4

I haven't kept up with all of the changes to the spring framework since 2.5. I am looking for a sample application for 4.0 that has a basic skeleton app with hibernate done the 4.0 way with controllers and services.

I've googled and looked at the spring site, which I think has been made much worse in the last year or so. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Spring Guides

Take look at [Spring Guides](http://spring.io/guides),
 all with Spring 4.0.

> (..) these guides are designed to get you productive as quickly as possible – using the latest **Spring** project releases and techniques as **recommended by the Spring team**.

I think tutorial [Data Access with Spring](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/) can help you,  especially step 3:

- [Storing Order Data Using the Java Persistence API (JPA)](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/3/)

with source code: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-data

There is also Getting Started Guide, designed to be completed in 15-30 minutes

- [Accessing Data with JPA](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

with source code: https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa.

This give you general look at possibilites. You can use solutions from this (like [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) etc) with or without [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

### Appfuse archetypes

There is also [Appfuse 3.0](http://appfuse.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=15990813) recently released with support for Spring 4.0.

> AppFuse is a full-stack framework for building web applications on the JVM. It was originally developed to eliminate the ramp-up time when building new web applications. Over the years, it has matured into a very testable and secure system for creating Java-based webapps.

AppFuse is full of good patterns, simply build new project from [appfuse archetype](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) and take look.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an interesting project that helps you to bootstrap your spring app as easy and fast as possible. You probably would like to take a look. [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for normal application (not a web application but integration of Spring 4 with hibernate 4) then you can refer to [My Blog](http://keyurj.blogspot.in/2014/01/spring-4-integration-with-hibernate-4.html). If you are interested in further integrate the same to Spring MVC you need to create controller class with annotation @Controller and autowire the same to respective Service class via @Service annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 4 comes with lot of new features. One of them is the support for Java 8 version. Here is the list of notable features included in the Spring 4 release.

1. Spring MVC Test Framework
2. Asynchronous MVC processing on Servlet 3.0
3. custom @Bean definition annotations in @Configuration classes
4. @Autowired and @Value to be used as meta-annotations
5. Concurrency refinements across the framework
6. loading WebApplicationContexts in the TestContext framework
7. JCache 0.5 (JSR-107)

Also you can read the list of [Spring 4 Tutorials](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-4/).